# How to get particular tag from an xml document in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I am using etree and lxml,

I am able to get the text of the node using the xpath, but I want the whole content including tags

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/> First Country
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/> Second Country
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/> Third Country
    </country>
</data>
```

If  I give country, I want the text to be returned as

```
<country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
            <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/> First Country
 </country>
```

Code am using right now is

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for i in tree.findall('.//country'):
    print i.text
```

Comment: Please also include (the relevant portion of) the Python code you have so far.

Comment: @Tomalak I have added the code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
for i in tree.findall('.//country'):
    print ET.tostring(i)
```